# Java JPA TypedQuery

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am trying to build a query, but I get an error when I argument the ids. I don't understand why.

This is for Java 8 + spring-data-jpa 1.11.23.RELEASE

```
public List<E> findByIds(List<Long> ids) throws Exception {

    try {

        TypedQuery typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(String.format("SELECT x FROM %s x WHERE x.id IN (?1)",domainClass.getSimpleName()),domainClass.getClass());
        typedQuery.setParameter(1, ids);
        return typedQuery.getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(value = AbstractEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable, Persistable<Long>
{

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "TABLE_GEN", table = "id_sequence", pkColumnName = "seq_name", valueColumnName = "seq_count", pkColumnValue = "Entity")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TABLE_GEN")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    ...
```

The error

> 16:02:45,103 ERROR DaoImpl:528 - You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.ArrayList for parameter 1 with expected type of class java.lang.Long from query string SELECT x FROM MyEntity x WHERE x.id IN (?1).
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.ArrayList for parameter 1 with expected type of class java.lang.Long from query string SELECT x FROM My_Entity x WHERE x.id IN (?1).
>
> at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:946)
> at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:920)
> at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:479)
> at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:1)

Answer (score 0):

this project is using

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Looks like they are not checking for "IN" operator

```
  protected void setParameterInternal(String name, Object value, boolean isIndex) {
    DatabaseQuery query = this.getDatabaseQueryInternal();
    if (query.getQueryMechanism().isJPQLCallQueryMechanism()) {
        int index = query.getArguments().indexOf(name);
        if (index == -1) {
            if (isIndex) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(ExceptionLocalization.buildMessage("ejb30-wrong-argument-index", new Object[]{name, query.getEJBQLString()}));
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ExceptionLocalization.buildMessage("ejb30-wrong-argument-name", new Object[]{name, query.getEJBQLString()}));
        }

        Class type = (Class)query.getArgumentTypes().get(index);
        if (!this.isValidActualParameter(value, type)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ExceptionLocalization.buildMessage("ejb30-incorrect-parameter-type", new Object[]{name, value.getClass(), query.getArgumentTypes().get(index), query.getEJBQLString()}));
        }
    } else if (isIndex && name.equals("0")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(ExceptionLocalization.buildMessage("ejb30-wrong-argument-index", new Object[]{name, query.getSQLString()}));
    }

    this.parameterValues.put(name, value);
}

protected boolean isValidActualParameter(Object value, Class parameterType) {
    return value == null ? true : BasicTypeHelperImpl.getInstance().isAssignableFrom(parameterType, value.getClass());
}
```

I will avoid using setParameter method.

Comment: Watch out! I've not used eclipselink (only hibernate for JPA) but not using parametrized queries, if you mean that, will expose you to SQL injection

Comment: Agree. I need to remove eclipse dependency.